# Adding "Third-party" link in "Share Page" sheet on Windows Phone 8 IE10

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am wondering if there is a possibility to add third-party app link in "Share Page" sheet in IE10 on Windows Phone 8.

For instance, when you like to share a url that you are browsing in your IE10 on Windows Phone 8, and would like to share that site or url, you tap on "..." and then from there you pick "share page" option and then you tap either "Tap+Send", "Hotmail" or "Gmail" and then "Social Network". However I would like to add a third-party link here just like when you try to share photos and there you see the third-party apps links.

So my question is does IE10 on Windows Phone 8 allows you to add "sharing extension" specifically or it is only blessed by Native Apps that are developed by Nokia, HTC or Microsoft?

See the "Share Page Sheet" (with options of sharing) here:

https://twitter.com/MMudassir/status/278584991091392512/photo/1

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a supported extensiblity point for WP7/WP8.

If you want to see that supported in the future open up a new [uservoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com) suggestion with your usecase on when consumers would need this functionality.